# Solving an algebraic equation with tangents and sinuses.

Tags: trigonometry

I got myself into a rather complicated algebraic equation with multiple instances of tangents and sinuses. While my calculator is able to solve it numerically, I would like to solve it algebraically. Does anyone have the knowledge how to solve the following equation algebraically?

$$\tan(x/2)=\frac{0.42*\sin(x/2)} {0.95-\frac{0.42*\sin(x/2)}{\tan(45-x/2)}}$$
to simplify: $k_1=0.42$, $k_2=0.95$, $t = \tan(x/2)$, $c = \cos(x/2)$ and $s = \sin(x/2)$ ($k_3$ = $k_1$),
so: $$t = \frac{k_1s}{k_2-\frac{k_1s}{Q}}$$
where $$Q = \frac{c-s}{c+s}$$

Edit:
I tried to rewrite it to $$s/c + \frac{\sin(45-x/2)}{\cos(45-x/2)} = k_1s / k_2$$
But I got stuck here.

Then, after Narasimham helped me, I tried to get to his solution:
$$ \dfrac{k_1+k_2}{k_3} = \dfrac{s(s+c)}{c-s} $$ 
But after getting to $$t= \frac{s}{c} = \frac{k_1s}{k_2-\frac{k_1s}{Q}} $$ 
then $$\frac{k_2}{k_1s} - \frac{\frac{k_1s}{Q}}{k_1s} = \frac{k_2}{k_1s} - \frac{1}{Q}$$

I didn't know how to proceed towards the solution. 
I would be very grateful if someone could help me!

Thanks in advance,
Lars

Comment: could you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Comment: Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used shorthand for sine , cos and tan as $ s, c, t $ for half angles. Hope it is ok.

$$ \dfrac{s}{c} = \dfrac{k_1 s}{k_2 - k_3 s / Q } $$

where $$ Q =  \tan ( \pi/4 - x/2) =\dfrac{1-t}{1+t} = \dfrac{c-s}{c+s}. $$

$$ \dfrac{k_1+k_2}{k_3} = \dfrac{s(s+c)}{c-s} $$

Comment: Thanks Narasimham! Could you elaborate how Q = t = 1-t/1+t ?

Comment: As edited. The parantheses are a pain? You should write $ Q=\frac{(1-t)}{(1+t)}$

Comment: No, that's not it, it's that I don't see how $$tan(π/4−x/2)= \frac {1−t} {1+t}$$

Comment: Can you look up the formula for $ \tan( A+B)?$

Comment: Ah yes, $tan (A+B) = \frac{tan (A) + tan (B)}{1 - tan (A) tan (B)} $. Very convenient with $tan (A)$ being 1! Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You know a way of saying that here?

Comment: I don't see what you're pointing at. I think the fact I just signed up for the website doesn't help.